# From DB they are sending HTML, how to render it in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am receiving an object like this

```
[
  {
    "BET": 57630343,
    "CUSTOMER": 181645,
    "SPORT": "MLB",
    "XX_FILL OPEN": "<button class=\"btn\" onclick=\"fillOpen(57630343)\">Fill Open</button>",
    "XX_VIEW": null,
    "XX_CANCEL": "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"sports\" value=\"soccer\"  onchange=\"fillOpen(57630343)\"/>"
  },...]
```

I am rendering that object in the DOM, but for now, looks like in the picture below

[image]

here is the HTML part for the dynamic table

```
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in cols" ng-init="isXX = column.indexOf('XX') === 0">
              <span ng-if="isXX">{{column.substring(3).replace('_', ' ')}}</span>
              <span ng-if="!isXX">{{column}}</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td ng-repeat="column in cols">
              <span>{{row[column]}}</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and here is the Angular part

```
    ReportsFactory.pendingBets(reportParam).then(function(data) {
      if (data.length) {
        gridInfo = _.forEach(data, function(item) {return item;});
        $scope.rows = gridInfo;
        $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.rows[0]);
      }
    }
```

The Database guys are sending me that data as you see it in the json I pasted above.

what I need to know, is, what should I do in order to render those elements in the DOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ngBindHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml#!) for that.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-repeat="column in cols" ng-bind-html="row[column]">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Since you're getting the HTML from a `$http` call, you have to use `$sce.trustAsHtml` to correctly display this HTML on every single one of your row columns that require this:

```
$scope.rows.forEach(function(row) {
    for (var key in row) {
        if (key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
            var value = row[key];
            if (value) {
                row[key] = $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Here's a working plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/7iFUhjg6Q0YIwRi47fDm?p=preview

Comment: no, actually your solution only displays text, what should I do to display the button and the input type checkbox ?

Comment: Are you including `ngSanitize` in your module definition? `angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])...`

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer upon trying this myself I realized that just ng-bind-html wasn't enough,  I edited my answer and added a working plunkr.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using ngSanitize.

Check it here. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Then, you can use `ng-bind-html` directive, which render HTML code to DOM element.

And, Javascript in the element can be applied with `trustAsHtml` method of `$sce` service.

I made an example here.
http://plnkr.co/edit/sTEUIWHwGXSAUSQ2rC8y?p=preview